# When i click on back button of the browser I am still in the same page Fullpage js

Tags: fullpage.js

I am trying to get back to my Home Page when i click on back button of the browser. but i can´t. Beacause of the url has parameters Example:

```
www.domain.com/#first
www.domain.com/#second
www.domain.com/#third
www.domain.com/#fourth
```

if i am in the url www.domain.com/#fourth.
How can i get to www.domain.com/ when i click the back button of the browser?
is It possible? Because what i only get is to get back to : www.domain.com/#third and then :
www.domain.com/#second

I try with this:

```
lockAnchors: true,
```

It Works.! But my anchors do not work because i locked them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can not be done.

If anchors work, they will work in all cases, as each anchor will be consider a new URL.

If not, they won't work in ANY case.